# Nuxt nested routing doesnt work 2 levels deep

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I'm trying to build a Nested Page in Nuxt using [this guide](https://nuxtjs.org/examples/routing/nested-pages/) and [this guide](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/nuxt-components/#the-nuxtchild-component) and running into a problem

What I want is:

1. foobar.com/2021 shows me the parent page for the year
2. foobar.com/2021/jun shows me the parent page content for the year + child page for the month
3. foobar.com/2021/jun/edit shows me the parent page content for the year + the 'edit' child page for that month.

In the above cases, both the '2021' part and the 'Jun' part will be dynamic

The problem:
I can get the first 2 to work but the not the edit route. This is what works currently:

/pages
_year.vue
_year/
_month.vue
index.vue

It's demonstrated in this [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-kepler-50kr1)

What I've tried to get the edit route to work:

1. Add a `_month` folder under `_year`, right alongside `_month.vue`
2. Add a `edit.vue` there
3. Add a `index.vue` in addition
4. Add a `<nuxt-child></nuxt-child>` to the `_month.vue`

All this worked([Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-nobel-pb70y?file=/pages/_year/_month.vue))but not exactly in the way I expected: It now shows the Month Content AND the edit content. Which makes sense because these steps convert the month and the edit into a parent-child nesting themselves. But I dont want that. I want `edit` to be a child of `year`. Is that not possible?