# Static page within dynamic nested route not generated on NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

My goal is to have the following page structure

```
pages
--/users/
--/users/:id/
--/users/:id/edit/
```

edit should be generated for every :id. **Right now my setup works only in development mode**. On nuxt generate only the first `/users/:id/edit/` is generated. All other routes get a 404 error on production!

Current setup:

```
- /users
   - index.vue
   /_id
      - index.vue
      - edit.vue
```

I also tried to add another _id.vue which i found [in the documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/examples/routing/nested-pages/#nested-pages) and [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing/#dynamic-nested-routes)

```
/users
   - _id.vue
   - /id 
   [...]
```

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70209373/nuxt-nested-routing-doesnt-work-2-levels-deep) as well.

In `nuxt.config.js` I have

```
ssr: true,
target: 'static',
```

Do I need to add something in router property in nuxt.config.js? I am not sure why it is not generated in production.

Comment: Where is your code hosted?

Comment: It is hosted on Netlify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using static site generation you have to define your static routes, because Nuxt does not know how many users do you have in your data base.

You can set a generate method into your `nuxt.config.js` file:

```js
  generate: {
    fallback: true,
    async routes() {
      const routes = await _getRoutes()

      return routes
    }
  }
```

And then declare a function called `_getRoutes` to generate a list of dynamic routes:

```js
async function _getRoutes($content) {
  const usersList = [1, 2, 3] // get from your DB
  const paths = []

  usersList.forEach((userId) => {
    paths.push(`/users/${userId}`)
    paths.push(`/users/${userId}/edit`)
  })

  return paths
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! This helped me fixing my problem. Not sure why the other routes have been generated though

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug with nuxt 2 in vue 2.

for dynamically generated routes, and also not-english nested routes ,
**(or maybe just generally non-english routes)** when vue hydrates the component , it will face a problem and restarts it . so the data that you cached in `data(){}` with `fetch()`, will be empty again .

currently you should use static and/or english-only routes .